# Adjusting X-Axis Labels for Dates ChartJS

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I have the following piece of js:

```js
var canvas_link = document.getElementById("chart1").getContext("2d");

  var myChart = new Chart(canvas_link, {
    
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      
      labels: xvalues,

      datasets: [{
        label: area_option,
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
      }]
    },
   

  
  })
```

This piece of code outputs the following graph:[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The labels underneath are really crowded and I wanted to just have a quarterly range on the x axis. The labels are currently in string format. Any advice will be very much appreciated since im having a hard time to understand the documentation. I tried to remove some of the values in the array for labels but that just results in unordered blanks. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special type of axis - [`time`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-cartesian-axis) and it can be used to automatically scale the X axis labels.

> The time scale is used to display times and dates.
>
> When building its ticks, it will automatically calculate the most comfortable unit based on the size of the scale.

`labels` option is not needed and `data` should be reshaped into array of `{ x: new Date('2020-12-01'), y: 123 }`.

```
const data = [
        { x: new Date('2020-12-01'), y: 123 },
        { x: new Date('2020-12-02'), y: 134 },
        { x: new Date('2020-12-03'), y: 154 },
        // etc.
],
```

X axis also needs to be configured to use `time` type (it does not seem to detect it automatically)

```
var myChart = new Chart(canvas_link, {
    
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      
      // labels: xvalues, (not needed)

      datasets: [{
        label: area_option,
        data: data, // note: should be new data not the old one
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
      }]
    },
   
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Date'
                },
                ticks: {
                    major: {
                        fontStyle: 'bold',
                        fontColor: '#FF0000'
                    }
                }
            }],
        }
    }
  
  })
```

You can find my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lojp8xr/1/).

**UPDATED**: X axis shows only quarters/months.

Adding `unit: 'quarter'` or `unit: 'month'` can group X axis labels by quarter or month.

Other supported units can be found in [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-units).

Updated version can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8amk0y6f/)

```
var myChart = new Chart(canvas_link, {

    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: data,
            label: 'Data',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        }]
    },

    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Date'
                },
                time: {
                    unit: 'quarter',
                },
                ticks: {
                    major: {
                        fontStyle: 'bold',
                        fontColor: '#FF0000'
                    }
                }
            }],
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This is perfect!! Thank you so much I shall have a test tomorrow and shall confirm the ans!!! Thank you so much for all the help!!! <3